# JQuery:Passing callback method with or without braces giving different results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I have this code blocks from W3Schools sample of JQuery. [Try it on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show) . I have only added one callback on the hide method call.

First Case

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script src="jquery.js"></script> <script> function sayHello(){ alert('hello sit'); }

$(document).ready(function(){   $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide(100,sayHello);   }); });

</script> </head> <body> <button>Hide</button> <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p> <p>This is another small paragraph.</p> </body> </html>
```

The second case is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script src="jquery.js"></script> <script> function sayHello(){ alert('hello sit'); }

$(document).ready(function(){   $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide(100,sayHello());   }); });

</script> </head> <body> <button>Hide</button> <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p> <p>This is another small paragraph.</p> </body> </html>
```

The only difference in both is passing the callback function with or without braces.

In first case, on click of hide button I am getting hello alert twice.
In second case I am getting hello alert only once.
I am expecting the alert to come only once in both cases as it doesn't matter for a zero args function to be called with or without braces.

I would like to understand why it is calling callback function twice when function name is passed without braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, you're passing the *result* of evaluating `sayHello()`, whereas in the first case, you're passing the *actual function* `sayHello`.

So because `sayHello` shows an alert, it will show the alert as soon as it's executed. In the first case, it's executed when `hide` is complete (as a callback), whereas in the second case it's executed when you set up the call to `hide()` (probably before the hide actually occurs).

<del>Not sure why it's executing twice, but</del> **(see below)** the version without parenthesis (version 1) is probably the version you're looking for if you want it to execute once `hide()` is complete.

**UPDATE:**

The reason it's showing the alert twice is that you're calling `hide()` twice. You have two different `<p>` elements, and `.hide()` is being called for each of them in turn (and the callback is being executed for each in turn likewise). I would guess if you add a third `<p>` tag it will alert a third time.

From the [JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

> If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

You probably want to encompass your elements in a parent element (like a `<div>`) and hide that instead of each individual `<p>` element.

Comment: ok, i understand the logic. Still why it is calling twice. the jquery documentation says "callbackA function to call once the animation is complete"

Comment: @sudmong Just spotted the answer, updating my answer with the reason.

Comment: @sudmong, that's because there are two `<p>` elements in your document. `hide()` calls your function once for each element that is hidden (and `this` is bound to the appropriate element for each call).

Comment: @sudmong Updated my answer with the explanation for multiple calls to `sayHello`.

Comment: @Pete, appreciate the support. I tried removing one <p> and results were consistent.Secondly, I agree callback is called for each element, then it should be called twice in both the cases with or without braces callback.

Comment: @sudmong, nope, it shouldn't. Read the answers again. The braces (they're parentheses, actually) are the difference between evaluating a function and calling that function. That's two very different behaviors.

Comment: @sudmong As Frédéric pointed out, the version with parentheses is actually evaluating the function. So `sayHello` is getting evaluated before the animation starts, not after it's over (if you pay close attention you'll notice that). It's not the effect you're looking for. You might be able to get the effect without a wrapper element by using a promise of some sort (check the `$.Deferred()` functionality of jQuery and related docs).

Comment: oh yes.. i overlooked the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

The two calls the entirely different. The first one passes the reference of the function as 2nd parameter to `hide` function. However, the second one makes a call to your `sayHello` function and passes the result of the call as 2nd parameter to the `hide` function. The `sayHello` function is called before your `hide` gets called.